# Converting a GroupBy / Having SQL query to Linq or EF query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT planet_id 
FROM tags 
WHERE name IN ('tag1', 'tag2') 
GROUP BY hardware_id 
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1;
```

where is 'tag1' and 'tag2' is the items of a `List<string>` that I pass to my function.  I want to know how to convert it to Entity Framework or Linq query.

Comment: See my answer for your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var tags=new List<string>{"tag1", "tag2"};
var query= from t in context.Tags
           where tags.Contains(t.Name)
           group t by t.hardware_id into g
           where g.Count()==1
```